# How to use ShouldVerb with Double types?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am new to using the fully fledged scalatest and the relatively new `ShouldVerb` in version 3.0.0 (ex `ShouldMatchers`). What I'd like to test is something along the lines of the following:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.words.ShouldVerb

class MyFunTest extends FunTest with ShouldVerb {
    test("the world makes sense") {
        math.abs(1.0 - (1.0 - 1e-10)) should be < 1e-9
    }
}
```

but this leads to the compiler error:

```
value should is not a member of Double
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs state that [ShouldVerb](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.words.ShouldVerb) "*Provides an implicit conversion that adds should methods to String to support the syntax of FlatSpec, WordSpec, fixture.FlatSpec, and fixture.WordSpec.*"

Hence, a `Double` will not be implicitly decorated with the *should* verb (only `String`).

An alternative (but arguably more verbose) assert version below if you want to use the verb style.

```
import org.scalatest.{ FlatSpecLike, Matchers }

class MathTests extends FlatSpecLike with Matchers {

  "Behavior of math.abs" should "return an absolute number blah blah blah..." in {
    assert(math.abs(1.0 - (1.0 - 1e-10)) < 1e-9)
  }

}
```